# how can increse timeline in dhtmlxGantt tool

Tags: laravel-5, gantt-chart

hellow, I am using dhtmlxgantt tool for project management in My laravel app. but in My time line I can only add till 2014-12-31 but I need increse My year till 2020. how can I do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done in a couple of different ways

1) You can define range using [start_date](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/api__gantt_start_date_config.html)/[end_date](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/api__gantt_end_date_config.html) options

```
gantt.config.start_date = new Date(2016, 0, 1);
gantt.config.end_date = new Date(2021, 0, 1);
gantt.init();//or gantt.render() if gantt is already initialized
```

2) Alternatively, you can tell gantt to always recalculate the time scale in order to [fit all data](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/api__gantt_fit_tasks_config.html) you have in gantt (by default such calculation happens only once when you load data)

```
gantt.config.fit_tasks = true;
```

Note, that you either set date range explicitly (define start/end dates), or tell gantt to calculate it automatically (use fit_tasks config), you can't enable both.

Then you can set the date picker range in the details form:

```
gantt.config.lightbox.sections=[
    {name:"description", height:70, map_to:"text", type:"textarea",focus:true},
    {name:"time", year_range: [2016, 2025]  map_to:"auto", type:"duration"}
];
```

http://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/desktop__duration.html

Note, that gantt may become slow when you display huge date range. Usually, it can be fixed by enabling static_background mode and smart rendering extension. http://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/desktop__performance.html  http://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/api__gantt_static_background_config.html